# What is the average amount of time you spend on a UX design process?

Tags: ux-designer, design-process, project-management

I know that the amount of time spent on a project will vary from project to project depending on what is required but I was wondering what is the average amount of time a UX person spends on each project?

If you were presented with having to conduct research, speaking to stakeholders and users, defining solutions, creating mockups, user testing and allowing time to make changes to the design. How long would you expect this to take on average?

Or if this is easier to imagine, what was the average amount of time you spent on each project in the last year?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's my personal opinion, For Example if our project is too small it can handle one or two persons in 3 days . If the project is too large our team of 6 to 7 in a week.